# When are electric candles permitted?

Tags: halacha, candle-lighting

I know that different rabbis have issued different rulings on whether it is permissible to light electric candles and recite the appropriate blessings. But do some rabbis permit it in some cases but not in others (Shabbat, Yom Tov, Hanukkah, Havdalah, yahrzeit, etc.)?  What is their rationale?

Comment: The version I heard is that this only applies to incandescent, as you’re literally burning something, though some permit even LEDs if you have absolutely nothing else. I haven’t heard anyone distinguish between why you’re lighting it.

Comment: I believe I've heard that (in the early 20th century?) Rav Chaim Ozer and Rav Menachem Krakowski, in Vilna, used to use incandescent lights for *havdalah* to show that it was considered fire (and forbidden on Sabbath).

Comment: @Loewian I’ve heard that too. I wonder if that would be a practical difference between the two reasons why we have fire at Havdalah - if it’s because fire was created Motzaei Shabbos, then any type of fire will do, but if it’s because now we can cook, then only fire which can cook can be used. By extension, you wouldn’t be able to use an incandescent light on Motzaei Yom Kippur, when only the second reason applies.

Answer (score 2):

From [Halachipedia](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Electricity_on_Shabbat&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop#Using_a_light_bulb_for_Shabbat_Candles_and_Havdala) (footnotes were just added inline parenthetically)

> If one does not have a way of lighting real candles, one may be
>   *yotze* by switching on electronic candles, and may recite the *bracha* too. [Shemiras Shabbos Kehilchasa 43:4, Rav Moshe Soloveitchik (quoted in Nefesh Harav pg. 155), Yabia Omer O.C. 2:17,
>   and Rav Henkin (Eidus LeYisrael p. 122)]
>
> Rav Ovadyah Yosef (Yalkut Yosef Shabbos vol 1 pg 188, Yabia Omer OC
>   2:17) agrees that one can make a *bracha* on it but emphasizes that
>   it's only as a last resort, and that one should preferably designate
>   the bulb for Shabbos candles.
>
> Rav Shlomo Zalman Aurebach (Shemiras Shabbos Kehilchasa (ch. 43 fnt.
>   22) held that using an electric bulb plugged into the wall is
>   questionable since the fuel to keep it lit on Shabbos wasn't present
>   at the time of the lighting. Rav Moshe Feinstein (quoted by Rabbi
>   Tendler in Moreshes Moshe v. 2 p. 51) agreed with this concern.
>   However, R' S.Z. did permit battery powered lights, where the charge
>   is all contained within.
>
> R' Moshe Feinstein and Shu"t Shraga Hameir (5:11) rule not to say the
>   blessing.
>
> Those who are forced to use the electric lights instead of candles
>   should turn on even those lights which are not normally used in order
>   for there to be some distinction that the electric lights are in honor
>   of Shabbos. (Tzitz Eliezer, V1 §20)
>
> Some hold that there is a difference between an incandescent bulb and
>   a fluorescent one. Rav Hershel Schachter (“Lighting Shabbos Candles,”
>   min 36-7) holds that while one may light an incandescent bulb with a
>   bracha, one may not light a fluorescent or neon bulb with a bracha.
>   Rav Yitzchak Yosef (Motzei Shabbat Parshat Chukat 5778 min 38) held
>   that any light even a florescent or LED light is effective for Shabbat
>   candles.
>
> In regards to Havdala, the *halacha* is the same. R' Chaim Ozer
>   Grodzinski would use electronic bulbs every Motze Shabbos to
>   demonstrate his position (he was one of the primary contenders to
>   promote the belief that creating an electric light is considered a
>   flame), according to Shaarim Metzuyanim Behalachah 96:6 and Nefesh
>   Harav pg. 156. Others, however, held that in regards to Havdala, one
>   cannot use electricity (R' Tzvi Pesach Frank, Har Tzvi 2:114).

Answer (score 2):

This source presents a logical argument in favor of using electric candles for commemorating a yahrzeit: http://halachayomit.co.il/en/default.aspx?HalachaID=3863

In short, it says: 
a) We do not say “Boreh Me’orei Ha’esh” over a yahrzeit candle
b) The candle is not meant to illuminate
c) Yahzeit candles are a minchag, not a mitzva
d) There are sources to rely on for using electric Shabbos candles
 
e) If we can use electric for a mitzva, surely we can use electric for a minchag
f) Rabbi Ovadia Yosef zt”l holds one use an electric light for a Yahrzeit for a parent

Answer (score -3):

In short:

1. Shabbos candles' goal is to increase lighting (to maximize Shlom Bays), therefore any lighting will do the job, incl. electricity. THe lights must be shut off before the blessing and lit back on.
2. Hannuka candles require a wick and a substance burning, so only candles will do. No electricity is Kosher here.
3. Yahrtzeit candles are pure Minhag, but they follow the Posuk "נר ה' נשמת אדם" (Mishlei 20) and therefore "require" a real candle when lighting at home, but it is customary to light electric "candle shaped" lamps in shuls or donor names boards. Of course, no blessing is said anyway.

Comment: I haven’t heard this before, where is it from?

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel What "it", that you didn't hear?

Comment: To respond: 1. Source? Source? Are you aware that many significant poskim disagree with your psak (as well as the fact that you state it unequivocally, where the poskim that permit it allow it only bedieved)? 2. Source? Source? Are you aware that many significant poskim disagree with your psak? 3. Source? Source?

Comment: I think you have a lot to add to some discussions on this site, and I have nothing against you, but please stop paskening here, especially without sources, and especially when you can be misunderstood by people!